# How to pass a numpy ndarray as a color in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to pass a ndarray into this line: `cv2.fillPoly(im, pts=[cnt],color=(centroid_color[0],centroid_color[1],centroid_color[2]))`

centroid_color looks like this: `[  0 255   0]` and is of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

However, I keep getting this error: TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric.

How would I convert this properly?

edit: my current updated code that still gets the same error:

```
im = cv2.imread('luffy.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    moment = cv2.moments(cnt)
    c_y = moment['m10']/(moment['m00']+0.01)
    c_x = moment['m01']/(moment['m00']+0.01)
    centroid_color = im[c_x,c_y]
    centroid_color = np.array((centroid_color[0],centroid_color[1],centroid_color[2]))
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    print type(centroid_color)
    cv2.fillPoly(im,cnt,centroid_color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a numpy array directly as color argument like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pts = np.array([[[10,40], [70,16], [100,90] ]], np.int32)
im = np.zeros([240,320, 3], np.uint8)
color = np.array((60,0,255))
cv2.fillPoly( im, pts, color)


cv2.imshow(" ", im)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Of course it is also possible (though unnecessary) to write it like this:

```
clr = np.array([255, 0, 128])
cv2.fillPoly( im, pts, color=(clr[0], clr[1], clr[2]))
```

**Edit:**
Opencv requires the color argument to be either an array of float or integer type. The type you get from a 3-channel RGB image is probably uint8. Try adding

```
centroid_color = centroid_color.astype(np.int32, copy=False)
```

before you pass the color argument to cv2.fillPoly!

The opencv error message is a little confusing here...

Comment: I don't understand. for some reason this code works, but mine still returns TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric. I am ensuring that my color argument is also a nparray.

Comment: do the other arguments - im and pts have to be in that specific data type for the whole thing to work?

Comment: I can't tell you what's wrong with your code because I don't know how you created `centroid_color`. I will edit my answer and try to get a little closer to your approach.

Comment: thanks. I have updated the question with the way that I am getting centroid_color

Comment: Now I see what's the problem here. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: `np.array((60,0,255))` does not work as color for `cv2.rectangle` in `3.1.0`. Also, `astype` will not change it. Windows + Python3 + amd64

Comment: I am having same issue. none of the solutions work. frankly defining a color variable should not be this hard!

Answer (score 9):

For me the only thing that worked:

```
self.points = np.int32(np.vstack([
    np.random.uniform(0, bounds[1], 3),
    np.random.uniform(0, bounds[0], 3)
]).T)
color = np.uint8(np.random.uniform(0, 255, 3))

c = tuple(map(int, color))
cv2.fillPoly(img, [self.points], color=c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed Automaton2000's answer but no luck in OpenCV 4.4.
After tried a thousand times I found that the `color` param must be passed as `list`, not `np.ndarray`. Meanwhile all the other params must be `np.ndarray`, not `list`. Well done, OpenCV, for wasting one hour of my time.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

pts = np.array([[[10, 40], [70, 16], [100, 90]]], np.int32)
im = np.zeros([240, 320, 3], np.uint8)
# color = np.array((60, 0, 255))  # Not working
color = [60, 0, 255]  # This works
cv2.fillPoly(im, pts, color)

cv2.imshow("Ah, opencv", im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

By the way, here's another example for `cv2.rectangle`

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

pts = np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0, 120, (10, 2)), np.random.randint(120, 240, (10, 2))], -1)
im = np.zeros([240, 240, 3], np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(im, tuple(pts[0, :2]), tuple(pts[0, 2:]), [255, 0, 255])

cv2.imshow("Ah, opencv", im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this comment! After 30 minutes of cv2 nonsense, you saved me from wasting another 30 minutes. I tried np_array with various data types, I tried tuple, but no, it must be a list. Thanks opencv.

Answer (score 0):

```
color = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=3).tolist()
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), color, 3)
```

Try to use .tolist()

It solved my problem.

You can find usage example on [this code](https://github.com/Taeyoung96/Yolo-to-COCO-format-converter/blob/master/main.py).